# Combining multiple strings into one from text file

Tags: python

[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22l2X.jpg)

I am using Python pandas/jupyter notebook, and I am having trouble getting the output of a text file to combine into one line. I imported a text file into Python, which I stored in variable AB. I then looped through the data within one of them columns in AB to retrieve the letters in that column, which I then saved in variable emailText.

My issue is that I cannot get the multiple lines of string that are stored in emailText to combine into one single-line string. I tried replacing line-breaks but that has not worked. Could anyone help me out? Screenshot attached

```
for letter in AB["level_0"]:
    emailText = letter
    emailText = "".join(emailText.split())
    emailText.replace("\n","")
    print emailText
```

Comment: `emailText = emailText.replace("\n","")` you didn't assign the return value

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Unfortunately even when I assigned the text replace a return value, it did not change the output.

Comment: Could the issue be that in your terminal the text wraps around so it looks like there are line breaks when really there are not? You could test this by printing to a file, opening in notepad, turning word-wrap off and seeing if it's a single line.

Comment: Give this a try: `print "".join("".join(x) for line in emailText.splitlines() for x in line.split())`.  This gives you a sequence of characters, no spaces, no line breaks / new lines.

Comment: Hi thanks for the code! Although I tried it and it still spits out multiple lines of strings. I have attached a new image. I just think for some reason it is not allowing the text to be read as a single string, because when I print out the output of the new emailText2 variable, it only gives the very last line.

Comment: It looks like your problem is each of the lines is actually a value in `AB["level_0"]`.  To test this, just add a comma to the end of `print emailText2` to make it `print emailText2,`.  print adds a newline automatically, but adding the comma prevents it from doing so.

Comment: New image attached. Still no luck unfortunately. The output is still the same. I'm starting to wonder if I should just try a different approach for what I need to do.

Comment: You reassign emailText on every loop through... it will only ever be a single 'letter' object... create the variable outside the loop and add to it on each iteration.

Comment: @BrandonHill You misunderstood.  Put your `print emailText2,` line back within your for loop and you will see that the newlines are not part of the text but are added when Python's print statement is executed without the trailing comma.  As was pointed out above the `print emailText2` outside the loop will only ever contain the latest value.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone! Galaxyan's code worked for me, which was similar to sberry's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join( [ "".join(letter.split()) for letter in AB["level_0"] ] ).replace('\n','')
```

Comment: @BrandonHill not a problem

Answer (score -2):

```
AB["level_0"] = AB["level_0"].replace('\n','', regex=True)
```